# Response of twilio RecordingRulesResource update method

Tags: twilio, video-recording

I am using twilio recording rule resource. My start recording and stop recording method is provided below. As a response of RecordingRulesResource update method for a particular room, I always get same value for the property of "date_updated". The StartRecording method and StopRecording method are called in differnt time. I was supposed to get different value of date_updated in StartRecording method and StopRecording method but I am getting same value for both. Why is this happening?

```
public void StartRecording(string roomSid)
        {
            
            TwilioClient.Init(twilioSetting.AccountSid, authToken);
            var recordingRules = RecordingRulesResource.Update(
                rules: new List<RecordingRule>(){
                    new RecordingRule(Twilio.Types.RecordingRule.TypeEnum.Include, true, null, null, null)
                },
                pathRoomSid: roomSid
            );

            return;
        }

 public void StopRecording(string roomSid)
        {
            
            TwilioClient.Init(twilioSetting.AccountSid, authToken);
            var recordingRules = RecordingRulesResource.Update(
                rules: new List<RecordingRule>(){
                    new RecordingRule(Twilio.Types.RecordingRule.TypeEnum.Exclude, true, null, null, null)
                },
                pathRoomSid: roomSid
            );
            return;

        }
```